# how do i get the selected radiobutton value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

this is my code to know, which radio-button has been selected, but getting error at line 6. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
Dim selected_option As String = "0"
        For i = 1 To 4
            Dim rdbName As String = "rb_option" & i
            Dim rdb As New RadioButton()
            rdb = CType(Me.Page.FindControl(rdbName), RadioButton)
            If rdb.Checked = True Then
                selected_option = i.ToString
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

There are 4 radio-button with ID `rb_option1`,`rb_option2`,`rb_option3` and `rb_option4`.

**Update**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px">
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
  <td style="width: 95%">
  <asp:Label ID="lbl_question" CssClass="frm_label" Text='<%# Eval("QUESTION")%>'runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option1" Checked='<%# IF(Eval("ANSWER")="1",true,false) %>' GroupName="answer" Text='<%# Eval("OPT1") %>' CssClass="frm_label" runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option2" Checked='<%# IF(Eval("ANSWER")="2",true,false) %>' GroupName="answer" Text='<%# Eval("OPT2") %>' CssClass="frm_label" runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option3" Checked='<%# IF(Eval("ANSWER")="3",true,false) %>' GroupName="answer" Text='<%# Eval("OPT3") %>' CssClass="frm_label" runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option4" Checked='<%# IF(Eval("ANSWER")="4",true,false) %>' GroupName="answer" Text='<%# Eval("OPT4") %>' CssClass="frm_label" runat="server" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
  </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Thank in advance !!

Comment: Post your markup too. Since you mentioned you are using a `Repeater` in the below comment, its likely that your ID's are `<repeaterID>_rb_option<i>`.

Comment: @channs please check my post now. :-)

Comment: @coders Where are you firing your VB code? Repeater ItemDataBound?

Comment: @channs no where, can you please suggestion what should i write and where ..??

Comment: @sbhomra i'm using code behind approach

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a RadioButton list? Then you can iterate through your radiobutton's in the following manner:

HTML:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Radio 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Radio 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Radio 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Radio 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 4
    For Each li As ListItem In RadioButtonList1.Items
        If li.Selected Then
               selected_option = li.Value
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Apologies if my VB.NET syntax is wrong (used to C#).

Comment: i'm using it in repeater, i felt easy to code using radio-button.

Comment: In my opinion, using a RadioButtonList would be much easier since you are grouping all your radio buttons together and can iterate through them all easily. I've updated my post to hopefully make it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Dim rdbName As String = "rb_option" & i
```

to this:

```
Dim rdbName As String = "ctl00_cpExamMaster_Repeater1_ctl01_rb_option" & i
```

Comment: If you do a View Source of the page, what are the ID's of the radio buttons you see?

Comment: for 3rd radio-button `ctl00_cpExamMaster_Repeater1_ctl01_rb_option3`

Comment: In the code-behind, while debugging, examine `Repeater1.Controls` for radio buttons and check their ID's.

Comment: didn't get you, please can you tell me, what should i do ?

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the above code. Start debugging. Use the Quick Watch window to check the items in `Repeater1.Controls`. You should come across the 4 radio buttons and their ID's.

Comment: @coders Is your repeater actually getting populated with data?

Comment: yes off-course, the error showing, when i'm submitting the data.

Comment: i checked the code `Dim rdbName As String = "rb_option" & i.ToString
            ' MsgBox(rdbName)
            Dim rdb As New RadioButton()
            rdb = CType(Repeater1.FindControl(rdbName), RadioButton)
MsgBox(rdb)` in the message box, it is showing nothing or null, is this helpful ??